# What is the advantage to playing a deck full of cards with locking abilities?

Tags: gwent

I've noticed some players playing decks filled with cards that use abilities to lock an enemy card. I typically run a deck that uses Deploy abilities, and therefore am usually unaffected by these lock cards. What benefit do they have besides stopping some damage-over-time abilities?

Answer (score 5):

Locking does not only stop damage-over-time abilities, it stops any other abilities that a card may have. This may include effects like:

- Resilience: locks stop resilience so units do not carry over to the next round (good against e.g. dwarves).
- Buffing: some units get buffed every time something happens (e.g. Skellige axemen). Locking them stops that.
- Consuming: locking stops consuming from happening.

This means that locking disrupts the core strategy of certain decks. For example, dwarf decks usually depend on carry over units so locking their big units prevents them from executing their win condition.